# connect to mssql server from php7

Tags: server, php, html, sql, mssql

I [installed mssql](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-connect-and-query-sqlcmd) and I have a mssql database.

I want to connect to this database through php7.

I'm using `PDO`

```
$dbh = new PDO ("dblib:host=hostname:portnum;dbname=dbname" , "username" , "password");
```

but it throws an exception that it cannot connect to database. What am I doing wrong?

I can only connect to it using `sqlcmd` from terminal

Comment: PDO_DBLIB Is no longer included after 5.3.  You need to use PDO_ODBC instead.

Comment: More information here... https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dn865013.aspx